# How can i interact with Chrome pop-up for USB connection in Python/Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, usb, webusb

i'm developing a Test Automation framework in Python using Selenium, Appium and Behave/Gherkin.

I'm developing the test of a device that is needed to be paired to Web App.
In particular, the Web App has been opened with Chrome browser and once the device is plugged-in via USB to PC, Chrome browser recognize it and shows the pop-up.

I need to simulate using code the selection of device and then click on Pair, in order to pair the device to web app.

How can i interact with it?
[image: USB pop-up chrome]
I'm not looking for to use the keyboard simulation because it isn't a good solution.

Could you please help me in this?

I found something about keyboard simulation using pyautogui such as:

```
def keyboard_simulation(username, password):
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.typewrite(username)
    pyautogui.press('tab')
    pyautogui.typewrite(password)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
```

and something about WebUSB API but about it, i can't understand if it useful to connect devices to browser.
[text](https://hackernoon.com/exploring-the-webusb-api-connecting-to-usb-devices-and-printing-with-tspltspl2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automation of the permission prompt shown by `navigator.usb.requestDevice()` is not currently supported by the Chrome DevTools Protocol and therefore isn't supported by Selenium.

To help the team prioritize this feature please add a comment to this Chromium issue asking for support for automating the WebUSB permission prompt:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1142566

Comment: i see that for BLE and USB devices the bug has been resolved https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1410257. Is it possible? Anyway, if it is correct, i cannot find anything about the implementation, specially for python.

Comment: Automation is now supported for Bluetooth (but not USB) in Chromium but I'm not aware of the progress for integrating this into the various frameworks like Selenium. I would file a feature request with the particular library you are using.

Comment: Thanks Reilly for the reply and support!
I'm using the Python + Selenium for WebApp Automation. May i open the feature request on my own or not?

Comment: Yes, you should open a feature request with the library you are using.

Comment: Thanks again Reilly! 
Should it be open directly on Selenium project (Git) or on Chromium project ?

Comment: Selenium. Chromium already supports the command but the Selenium library needs to learn how to send it.

Comment: Thank too much Reailly! 
I opened a new feature proposal to Selenium project! 
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/13346